# How to use docker in a gitlab-ci job?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to be able to use the nodejs image and then execute docker commands in the same job. My gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - publish

before_script:
  - docker login -p $PW -u $USERNAME private-repo

release-docker:
  image: node:6.9.1
  stage: publish
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - npm install
    - docker build -t image-name .
    - other commands..
```

Although I'm defining the docker service, I'm getting the following error:

```
$ docker info
/bin/bash: line 47: docker: command not found
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: What is `docker:latest`? Where does it live?

Comment: Is the official docker image

Comment: So you want to do nested-docker-in-a-docker?  It seems to me the docker command inside another docker container is not a good idea.

Comment: So what should I do if I want to build and publish a docker image for my nodejs application?

Comment: I know how to build and publish docker images, I want to do it inside the gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: I think you might find there are docker-inside-docker images available on docker hub. Finding that is probably off topic for this site.   Maybe change image to `docker:somethingelse`.